# What does it mean to have zero mean in the data?

Tags: normalization, pca, feature-selection

I'm trying to find ways to normalize my dataset (represented as a matrix with documents as rows and columns as features) and I came across a technique called feature scaling. I found a Wikipedia article on it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling).

One of the methods listed is Standardization which says "Feature standardization makes the values of each feature in the data have zero-mean and unit-variance." What does that mean (no pun intended)?

In this method, "we subtract the mean from each feature. Then we divide the values (mean is already subtracted) of each feature by its standard deviation." When they say 'subtract the mean', is it the mean of the entire matrix or the mean of the column pertaining to that feature?

Also, if this feature scaling method is applied, does the mean not have to be subtracted from columns when performing Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on the data?

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to do a simple (and reversible) transformation on your dataset set to make it easier to handle. You are subtracting a constant from each column and then dividing each column by a (different) constant. Those constants are column-specific.

> When they say 'subtract the mean', is it the mean of the entire matrix
>   or the mean of the column pertaining to that feature?

The mean of the column pertaining to that feature.

> ...does the mean not have to be subtracted from columns when performing Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on the data?

Correct. PCA requires data with a mean of zero. Usually this is enforced by subtracting the mean as a first step. If the mean has already been subtracted that step is not required. However, there is no harm in performing the "subtract the mean" operation twice. Because the second time the mean will be zero, so nothing will change. Formally, we might say that standardization is idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the article, my understanding is that you would subtract the mean of that feature. This will give you a set of data for the feature that describes the same layout of the data but normalized.

Imagine you added data for a new feature. You're probably going to want the data for your original features to remain the same, and not be influenced by the new feature.

I guess you would still get a "standardized" range of values if you subtracted the mean of the whole data set, but that would be something different - you're probably more interested in how the data of a single feature lies around its mean.

You could also have a look (or ask the question) on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/).